# Request for historical precedent of identity implying AM-HM inequality

Tags: inequality, reference-request, induction

(That title's quite a mouthful, isn't it?)

A lot of my answers, though derived independently, are not new, and I often acknowledge this.
However, I recently came up with a result that was new to me, so I am asking if it is really new.

My result came up while attempting to find an inductive proof of the inequality between the arithmetic and harmonic means. This is the question:

[How can I prove that $(a_1+a_2+\dotsb+a_n)(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{a_n})\geq n^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145187/how-can-i-prove-that-a-1a-2-dotsba-n-frac1a-1-frac1a-2-dotsb-f/3145597#3145597)

This is the inequality
between the
arithmetic and harmonic means.

I eventually came up with this identity, which I do not recall having seen before:

Let
$s_n
=u_nv_n
$
where
$u_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k,
v_n= \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{a_k}
$.

Then

> $s_{n+1}
> =(\sqrt{s_n}+1)^2+\dfrac1{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}(\sqrt{u_n}-a_{n+1}\sqrt{v_n})^2
> $.

Since $s_1 = 1$, this immediately shows that
$\sqrt{s_{n+1}}
\ge \sqrt{s_n}+1$
so that
$\sqrt{s_n} \ge n$,
$s_n \ge n^2$ and the condition for
$s_{n+1} = s_n+1$
is
$a_{n+1}
=\sqrt{\dfrac{u_n}{v_n}}
=\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{a_k}}}
$.

So, my question is "Is this identity new?"

Of course the answer is probably "No", but a reference would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small error in your recurrence equation, it should be

> $s_{n+1}
> =(\sqrt{s_n}+1)^2+\dfrac1{\color{red}{a_{n+1}}}\bigl(\sqrt{u_n}-a_{n+1}\sqrt{v_n}\bigr)^2$

or, equivalently,

> $s_{n+1}
> =(\sqrt{s_n}+1)^2+\bigl(\dfrac{\sqrt{u_n}}{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}-\sqrt{a_{n+1}}\sqrt{v_n}\bigr)^2$.

This is a special case of the [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)
$$
 (a^2 + b^2)(c^2+d^2) = (ac+bd)^2 + (ad-bc)^2 
$$
applied to
$$
 (a, b, c, d) = (\sqrt{u_n}, \sqrt{a_{n+1}},  \sqrt{v_n}, \dfrac 1{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}) \, .
$$

Comment: Your comment is correct and your mapping of the identity into the Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity is ingenious. Accepted.